# Using Excel (formula or VBA) to substitute from a named table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm hoping to use Excel to generate HTML for me with substitutions. I've used Excel for HTML generation plenty of times before to quickly convert a lot of identically formatted Word document content into something I can copy and paste into code view, usually in the form of something like so (simplified)

```
=CONCAT("<h2>",[@Title],"</h2><p>",[@Description],"</p><a href='",[@Link],"'>Read More</a>")
```

Anyway, the latest conversion that has my ADHD screaming is a glossary with plenty of cross-referenced terms. So far I've built 2 named tables, Definitions and Keywords. Definitions looks like so, including what kind of output I'm trying to generate:

| Term | Definition | Definition HTML (in theory) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Digital Certificate | An encrypted digital attachment that is issued by a certificate authority. It enables the licensed professional to digitally authenticate and validate professional work products (PWPs) and it enables the recipient of the PWP to verify the professional status of the licensed professional. | <p>An encrypted digital attachment that is issued by a <em class="term">certificate authority</em>. It enables the <em class="term">licensed professional</em> to digitally authenticate and validate <em class="term">professional work products</em> (PWPs) and it enables the recipient of the PWP to verify the professional status of the <em class="term">licensed professional</em>.</p> |
| Direct Supervision and Control | The high degree of guidance a licensed professional provides to one or more individuals. The licensed professional accepts professional responsibility for engineering or geoscience tasks performed under their guidance. Direct supervision and control includes directing, monitoring, and controlling the engineering and geoscience work performed, including making all decisions related to the practices of engineering and geoscience. | <p>The high degree of guidance a <em class="term">licensed professional</em> provides to one or more individuals. The <em class="term">licensed professional</em> accepts professional responsibility for <em class="term">engineering</em> or <em class="term">geoscience</em> tasks performed under their guidance. <em class="term">Direct supervision and control</em> includes directing, monitoring, and controlling the <em class="term">engineering</em> and <em class="term repeat">geoscience</em> work performed, including making all decisions related to the practices of <em class="term">engineering</em> and <em class="term">geoscience</em>. </p> |

Keywords is a single column table like so

**Term**

- Authentication
- Bidding
- Certificate Authority

(the same data as Term column from Definitions, since I figured it would be tidier to have that as its own table and avoid accidentally building any circular logic)

I'm trying to get something like

```
=SUBSTITUTE([@Definition],Keywords[Term],CONCAT("<em class='term'>",Keywords[@Term],"</em>"))
```

which is obviously not correct/real, but hopefully you get the picture. I'm also willing to solve this with VBA, though I'm not as strong with it as I am Formulas.

Comment: Please show sample data of `Term column from Definitions` in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Office 365 you could use REDUCE: to iterate through the terms and replacing them on the original text:

`=REDUCE("<p>"&B2&"</p>",F$2:F$11,LAMBDA(definition,term,SUBSTITUTE(definition,term,"<em class=""term"">"&term&"</em>")))`

Note that SUBSTITUTE is case sensitive, so include the `LOWER()` version of your text:

`F1:F11`:

| Terms |
| --- |
| Authentication |
| Bidding |
| Certificate Authority |
| Licensed Professional |
| Professional Work Products |
| authentication |
| bidding |
| certificate authority |
| licensed professional |
| professional work products |

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! The formula I used with named ranges is  
    `=REDUCE("<p>"&[@Definition]&"</p> ",Keywords[Term], LAMBDA(definition, term, SUBSTITUTE(definition, term,"<em class=""term"">"&term&"</em>")))`